# How to sign URL for Google Cloud Storage upload (PUT) without MD5 checksum on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, google-cloud-storage, self-signed, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to generate a signed URL in AWS Lambda to upload (put) an object to GCS.

I've got this code (http://dpaste.com/20QWFRG) from various examples, and it works as is. But as soon as I remove MD5 checksum from being passed a header while signing, which is supposed to be optional (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually) it gives me error.

Here's the same code without the MD5 checksum being passed as a header and it **doesn't** work: http://dpaste.com/2ZH1VVP

Comment: first link is dead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `Content-MD5` is a Very Bad Idea™.  It's technically optional, but it should not be, because it's critical for data integrity.

But if you insist... the problem with your signing code is that you are eliminating the *blank line* that goes where the payload MD5 hash should have been.

> Note: After each step of the string construction, add a newline to the string (`\n`).
>
> https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually

So you need...

```
signature_string = ('{verb}\n'
                    '\n'
                    '{content_type}\n'
                    ...
```

The string-to-sign always has the same number of `\n`-delimited lines, even if some lines are left blank for optional values.

Because the string-to-sign is used as the input for HMAC and then discarded, the service has no way to make allowances for deviations from the exact format, no matter how small.

Comment: wow...can't believe that was the issue :( I thought it meant only add the \n when you are specifying values.

Thanks for the help. My use case needs the non-MD5 checksum method for now. The plan is to keep a lookout for any issues and implement it if it comes up